# iOS/Mac OS: Saving and comparing CGPoints/NSPoints in Arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, enumeration, cgpoint

My intention is to compare `CGPoints` or `CGPoint` values (and as the app is also for Mac OS `NSPoints` or `NSPoint` values) of several moving objects to detect if the objects have the same position.

My first solution to this was to fast enumerate an array of those objects and store all `CGPoints` to an array, then fast enumerate the array of objects again to check whether the position is the same of any other object:

```
// STEP 1: Collect all Positions
NSMutableArray *allPositions = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.allObjects.count];
for (Object *myObject in self.allObjects) {
    CGPoint myObjectPosition = ...;
    [allPositions addObject:myObjectPosition]; // Problem here
}

// STEP 2: Check for Overlapping
for (Object *myObject in self.allObjects) {
    CGPoint myObjectPosition = ...;
    if ([allPositions containsObject:myObjectPosition] {
        // Overlapping
    }
}
```

The problem with this is adding the points to the `allPositions` Array. Therefore `NSValue` can be used:

```
[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point];
```

But this does work only under iOS, for Mac OS there has to be used `valueWithPoint` and `NSPoint`.

Can I save maybe save the `x` and the `y` values in dictionaries and store them to the `allPositions` Array? Or is there an even better solution without having 2x fast enumerations? There are about 100 objects in `self.allObjects`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*CGPoint* and *NSPoint* are the same struct. It doesn't matter if they got a different name, they both hold two *CGFloat*. They got the same size and the same alignment, and therefore they can be used interchangeably. So in your case *valueWithPoint:* fits.

**Edit**

About the second thing you ask, this should be done with macros:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    value= [NSValue valueWithCGPoint: point];
#else 
    value= [NSValue valueWithPoint: point];
#endif
```

Getting the point back:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    point= value.CGPointValue;
#else
    point= value.pointValue;
#endif
```

http://sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2010/8/16/TargetConditionalsh.html

Comment: The code should be valid for iOS and Mac OS. `valueWithPoint` will only work if the target is Mac OS. Building with an iOS target leads to an error `No known class method for 'valueWithPoint:'`...

Comment: You solve this using a macro to execute conditional code, according to the platform (see the edit).

Comment: ok but then when converting back a typecast is still needed for one platform (see comment by Parag Bafna). Can you please update your code for converting the NSValues back to points?

Comment: I added the code to get the point back, but you don't need a cast, they're the same type. Like Bafna pointed out it's : typedef CGPoint NSPoint;". Try it, you'll get no errors nor warnings.

Answer (score 1):

While working on universal iOS/OSX app i solved this problem by using NSValue category.
NSValue+CGPoint.h:

```
@interface NSValue (CGPoint)
#if TARGET_OS_MAC
+ (NSValue *)valueWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)point;
- (CGPoint)CGPointValue;
#endif
@end
```

NSValue+CGPoint.m:

```
#import "NSValue+CGPoint.h"
@implementation NSValue (CGPoint)
#if TARGET_OS_MAC
+ (NSValue *)valueWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    return [NSValue valueWithPoint:point];
}

- (CGPoint)CGPointValue {
    return [self pointValue];
}
#endif
@end
```

Now i can use the same code on both iOS and Mac, for example:

```
// store point in NSValue
CGPoint p = {10, 10};
NSValue *v = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:p];

// read point from NSValue
CGPoint p2 = [v CGPointValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//NSGeometry.h  
  typedef CGPoint NSPoint;

//CGGeometry.h
struct CGPoint {
  CGFloat x;
  CGFloat y;
};
typedef struct CGPoint CGPoint;
```

`NSPoint` and `CGpoint` are same;

```
// NSValue/+valueWithPoint:(NSPoint)point is available on Mac OS X
// NSValue/+valueWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)point is available on iOS


//save value in CGPoint

if([NSValue respondsToSelector:@selector(valueWithPoint:)])
{
    NSPoint lPoint = NSPointFromCGPoint(lCGPoint);
    // do some op
}
else {
    // do some op
}
```

EDIT

Dont use `respondsToSelector`, use `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` macro.

Comment: I know that they both hold `CGFloat x, y`. But if you look at several class references you'll notice that Mac OS methods only work with NSPoint and iOS methods only work with CGPoint. I have no idea how to get a universal solution...

Comment: You can type cast.use NSPointFromCGPoint

Comment: is it also possible the other way? NSPoint -> CGPoint?

Comment: With the macro *TARGET_OS_IPHONE* you know at compile time on what platform you are. Doing this choice at runtime is wrong and a wastage of resources.